# Javascript replace a URL based on two different button clicks

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to replace the `src` for various images on a house based on which button was clicked.

There are two sets of buttons.

1. The house part types e.g. windows, door, garage, soffits and gutters.
2. The colours e.g. red, green, blue

If windows was the last button of the types clicked and blue was the last colour I want to replace the windows with the blue windows image.

I tried doing a foreach to listen to the button click on each colour and then use a function but the function was unaware of the colours outside of the foreach.

Then I nested the foreaches and the function within, which worked, but it returns a value for each foreach based on the buttons you click.

Firstly I wanted to know if my methodology was correct as it doesn't feel right having a foreach within a foreach for this purpose.  It feels like they should be separate.  But I couldn't access the variable outside of the foreach.

Secondly, I wanted to know how can I only return the last result.  I tried checking the `array` `-1` but I think it is just returning the first letter.  I'm sure this is because it is not an array but a foreach loop.

```js
// Get all the button elements
const housePartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.houseParts');
const housePartColourButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".colours");


// Add a click event listener to each button
housePartButtons.forEach(housePartButton => {
    housePartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Get the value of the "data-housePartTypes" attribute
        const currentHousePartType = housePartButton.getAttribute('data-houseParts');
        // console.log(currentHousePartType);
        let lastHousePart = currentHousePartType[currentHousePartType.length - 1];

        housePartColourButtons.forEach(housePartColour => {
            housePartColour.addEventListener('click', () => {
                // Get the value of the "data-housePartTypes" attribute
                const currentHousePartColour = housePartColour.getAttribute('data-housePartColour');

                let lastPartColour = currentHousePartColour[currentHousePartColour.length - 1];


                let housePartImages = document.querySelectorAll(".housePartImages");
                // let houseParts = document.querySelectorAll(".houseParts");
                // let housePartColour = document.querySelectorAll(".colours");

                function imageColour(lastHousePart, lastPartColour) {
                    if (housePartColour == "white") {
                        function whiteImage() {
                            Array.prototype.forEach.call(housePartImages, function (el) {
                                el.classList.remove("show");
                                el.classList.add("hide");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        housePartTypeSrc = lastHousePart + ".src = " +
                            "https://upvc.squareballoon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/" + lastHousePart + "/" +
                            lastPartColour +
                            ".png";
                    }


                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(housePartImages, function (el) {
                        el.classList.add("show");
                        el.classList.remove("hide");
                    });
                }
                imageColour(lastHousePart, lastPartColour);
                console.log(housePartTypeSrc);

            });
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="type-holder">
            <button id="windows" class="white-button tcb-button-link houseParts"
                data-houseParts="windows">Windows</button>
            <button id="door" class="white-button tcb-button-link houseParts" data-houseParts="door">Doors</button>
            <button id="soffitsAndGutters" class="white-button tcb-button-link houseParts"
                data-houseParts="soffitsAndGutters">Soffits and Gutters</button>
            <button id="garage" class="white-button tcb-button-link houseParts" data-houseParts="garage">Garage</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-holder">
            <button id="button--white" class="white-button tcb-button-link colours" data-housePartColour="white">See it
                in
                White</button>
            <button id="button--brown" class="buttons tcb-button-link colours" data-housePartColour="brown">See it in
                Brown</button>
            <button id="button--pearl-green-6035" class="buttons tcb-button-link colours"
                data-housePartColour="pearl-green-6035">See it in
                Pearl Green
                6035</button>
            <button id="button--pearl-ruby-3032" class="buttons tcb-button-link colours"
                data-housePartColour="pearl-ruby-3032">See
                it in Peal
                Ruby
                3032</button>
            <button id="button--anthracite-grey-7016" class="buttons tcb-button-link colours"
                data-housePartColour="anthracite-grey-7016">See it
                in
                Anthracite Grey
                7016</button>
            <button id="button--midnight-blue-5011" class="buttons tcb-button-link colours"
                data-housePartColour="midnight-blue-5011">See it
                in
                Midnight Blue
                5011</button>
        </div>

        <div class="image-holder">
            <img id="image--house" src="https://upvc.squareballoon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/house-001.jpg">
            <img id="windows" class="housePartImages"
                src="https://squareballoon.co.uk/images/upcv-spraying/windows---brown.png">
            <img id="door" class="housePartImages"
                src="https://squareballoon.co.uk/images/upcv-spraying/door---brown.png">
            <img id="garage" class="housePartImages"
                src="https://squareballoon.co.uk/images/upcv-spraying/garage---brown.png">
            <img id="gutters" class="housePartImages"
                src="https://squareballoon.co.uk/images/upcv-spraying/soffits-and-gutters---brown.png">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="house-colour.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a small example of how I would implement it, although I'm not quite sure what you intend with some parts of your code. But I think you can adapt mine and it will work.

```js
const BASE_URL = "https://upvc.squareballoon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/";

// Get all the button elements
const housePartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.houseParts');
const housePartColorButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.colours');
const housePartImages = document.querySelectorAll(".housePartImages");

// Store last clicked house
let selectedHouse = null;
// Store last clicked color
let selectedHousePartColor = null;

// Add one event listener per button
housePartButtons.forEach((housePartButton) => {
  housePartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectedHousePart = housePartButton.getAttribute('data-houseParts');
  });
});

// Add one event listener per button
housePartColorButtons.forEach((housePartColorButton) => {
  housePartColorButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    selectedHousePartColor = housePartColorButton.getAttribute('data-housePartColour');
    // If we have a selected house part and a selected button: adjust the color
    if (!selectedHousePart || !selectedHousePartColor) return;
    imageColour(selectedHousePart, selectedHousePartColor);
  });
});

function imageColour(selectedHousePart, selectedHousePartColor) {
  // Your function goes here, not quite sure what you really trying to do here 
  console.log("House Part: ", selectedHousePart, " with color: ", selectedHousePartColor);
  const src = BASE_URL + selectedHousePart + "/" + selectedHousePartColor + ".png";
  console.log("Adjust Src: ", src)
}


// Note sure, why you've added those?
function showAll() {
  housePartImages.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.add("show");
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  });
}

function hideAll() {
  housePartImages.forEach((el) => {
    el.classList.remove("show");
    el.classList.add("hide");
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="type-holder">
  <button id="windows" class="white-button tcb-button-link houseParts" data-houseParts="windows">Windows</button>
  <button id="door" class="white-button tcb-button-link houseParts" data-houseParts="door">Doors</button>
  <button id="soffitsAndGutters" class="white-button tcb-button-link houseParts" data-houseParts="soffitsAndGutters">Soffits and Gutters</button>
  <button id="garage" class="white-button tcb-button-link houseParts" data-houseParts="garage">Garage</button>
</div>

<div class="button-holder">
  <button id="button--white" class="white-button tcb-button-link colours" data-housePartColour="white">See it in White</button>
  <button id="button--brown" class="buttons tcb-button-link colours" data-housePartColour="brown">See it in Brown</button>
  <button id="button--pearl-green-6035" class="buttons tcb-button-link colours" data-housePartColour="pearl-green-6035">See it in Pearl Green 6035</button>
  <button id="button--pearl-ruby-3032" class="buttons tcb-button-link colours" data-housePartColour="pearl-ruby-3032">See it in Peal Ruby 3032</button>
  <button id="button--anthracite-grey-7016" class="buttons tcb-button-link colours" data-housePartColour="anthracite-grey-7016">See it in Anthracite Grey 7016</button>
  <button id="button--midnight-blue-5011" class="buttons tcb-button-link colours" data-housePartColour="midnight-blue-5011">See it in Midnight Blue 5011</button>
</div>

<div class="image-holder">
  <img id="image--house" src="https://upvc.squareballoon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/house-001.jpg">
  <img id="windows" class="housePartImages" src="https://squareballoon.co.uk/images/upcv-spraying/windows---brown.png">
  <img id="door" class="housePartImages" src="https://squareballoon.co.uk/images/upcv-spraying/door---brown.png">
  <img id="garage" class="housePartImages" src="https://squareballoon.co.uk/images/upcv-spraying/garage---brown.png">
  <img id="gutters" class="housePartImages" src="https://squareballoon.co.uk/images/upcv-spraying/soffits-and-gutters---brown.png">
</div>
```

Comment: To answer your question before I ask another.  The reason we have show/hide is because the original image has white everything.  We don't need any of the overlaid images for that part.

Comment: To add a question.... I need to target by the ID of the house part, the URL structure is great but I need to replace the URL of the particular window part but I think I can do that.

Comment: This `let selectedHouse = null;` should be `selectedHousePart` right?

Comment: I tried `document.getElementById(selectedHousePart).src = BASE_URL + selectedHousePart + "/" + selectedHousePartColor + ".png";` why doesn't that change the image src?

Comment: worked it out, I had duplicate IDs on the buttons and images.  There was no SRC on the buttons (obviously).  Thank you.